# How can I find all signatures(overloads) of a method in Roslyn in a class or partial class files?

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Via Roslyn, C# syntax ,I have IMethodSymbol to clarify my method information,

```
var symbolMethod = context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(invocation).Symbol as IMethodSymbol;

if (symbolMethod == null) return;
//-- Here I need to get other signature of the symbolMethod
```

Notation: the container class maybe has partial class which includes some signature of this method

Comment: What do you mean with "all signatures"? Are you talking about overloads?

Comment: yes overloads is i mean

Comment: There is an implementation ````IsOverloaded```` in the Roslyn source code, which checks if methods are overloaded. It seems to be part of a more specific use case. Hence, I do not know, if it handles all possible cases: http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation/CodeModel/ExternalElements/ExternalCodeFunction.cs,c7a128fde9f1e994,references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var symbolMethod = context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(invocation).Symbol as IMethodSymbol;
//has several signatures
if (symbolMethod.ContainingType.GetMembers().Count(it => it.Name == symbolMethod.Name) > 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just do symbolMethod.ContainingType, and from there you can call GetMembers to get all members of the type. You can filter by name or whatever you're looking to get from there.

Answer (score 3):

You could look into `SemtanticModel.GetMemberGroup`:

```
var overloads = model.GetMemberGroup(invocation.Expression);
```

It returns a list of overloads of the method